# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que esta consulta me funcione en un controlador en laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
 select Id, total, @total := @total + total as cumulative_sum 
 from movimientos, (Select @total := 0) as total
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estuve investigando un poco y encontré la solución a mi pregunta El cual era 
crear un contador o acumulador en la vista blade de laravel y que sume los valores de dicha tabla

Bueno también existe otro método que seria crear una función en el controlador

Fuente de Ayuda :  [calculating-cumulative-values-in-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185507/calculating-cumulative-values-in-laravel)

bueno sin mas que decir los dejo aquí mi pequeño aporte ...!!!

```html
<?php $acumulador = 0; ?>

  @foreach ($movimientos as $m)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$m->fecha_hora}}</td>
        <td>{{$m->nombre_proveedor}}</td>
        <td>{{$m->descripcion}}</td>
        <td>S/.{{$m->ingreso}}</td>
        <td>S/.{{$m->salida}}</td>
        <td>S/.{{$m->total}}</td>
        <?php $acumulador += $m->total; ?>
        <td>{{$acumulador}}</td>
    </tr> 
 @endforeach
```

Adjunto la imagen de mi simple reporte hecho en laravel y vue

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]